# Can't login with root user in native templates of environments Jelastic

Tags: ssh, root, jelastic

When I create a new environment in some nodes, (i.e. with the Nginx) I can't access to this node with root user

[image]

I logged with user a not with root.

```
Using username "251X-XXX".
Authenticating with public key "rsa-key-XXXXXXXX"
Last login: Thu Sep 28 09:11:56 2017
nginx@node251X-delete ~ $ sudo date

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for nginx:
Sorry, try again.
```

Brief:

- I **didn't receive root password** to my email (I'm the owner of this environment).
- I **can't change** this node to a Docker image
- There's no **Reset Password** option on Dashboard
- Sudo it **doesn't work**.
- Also it happens with other non-docker nodes (Tomcat, MySQL,...)

Any alternative or configuration to enter with root user to this node.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jelastic doesn't provide root access to separate containers. At the same time while accessing containers via SSH, a user receives all required permissions and additionally can manage the main services with **sudo** commands of the following kind (and others):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/jetty start
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/tomcat restart
sudo /etc/init.d/memcached status
sudo /etc/init.d/mongod reload
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx upgrade
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd help
```

For example, you can restart nginx with the following command:

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

No password will be requested.

> **Note**: If you deploy any application, change the configurations or add any extra functionality via SSH to your Jelastic environment, this
>   will not be displayed at the Jelastic dashboard.

Using our documentation you’ll find out how to:

[use SFTP and FISH protocols](http://ops-docs.jelastic.com/ssh-protocols)

[manage containers via SSH with Capistrano](http://ops-docs.jelastic.com/ssh-capistrano)

Comment: So, I can't execute sudo yum install <package> on a Jelastic container?

Comment: You can manage only the main services with sudo commands according to the type of the container. In order to get true root access, you should create an environment with Virtual Private Server with CentOS or Ubuntu (please read more https://docs.jelastic.com/vps).

Comment: @albertoiNET, could you describe your case? what exactly do you miss in Jelastic containers?

Comment: @Ruslan I miss a root access. I know that exist topology based on Docker images, so I could use that, but I'm trying to avoid this way.

Comment: @albertoiNET, can you tell me please why you need it exactly? which packages do you need to install additionally?

Comment: It's not relevant to know which packages.

Comment: It would really help to know what you want to install because then maybe we can provide a solution (except Docker / Elastic VPS as already mentioned in my answer)

Comment: @Jelastic, sorry for the reopen the question. But my app works with npm in order to loader some dependencies and libraries of our project. I'm trying to install nodejs and npm to load that files, but I'm stucked with no root access in a single nginx container. I can't believe I need to upload to git all node_modules folder. Is there some reasonable solution?

Comment: @ThiagoA.Klein talk to your hosting provider. For example we built an node.js / npm 'add-on' that can be added to php and ruby containers, e.g. for project build purposes as I think you described. Your hosting provider may have a similar solution or should be able to assist you in some way.

Answer (score 2):

Root user is only provided for self-managed nodes (custom Docker / Elastic VPS).

You can execute specific whitelisted commands with `sudo` (e.g. `sudo service nginx restart`). Besides that you shouldn't need root access.

If you feel otherwise then contact your hosting provider to discuss your needs and they can find a solution for you.

Comment: Where I find whitelisted commands? When I executed 'sudo service nginx restart' also ask me for a password :(